# Utility function with constant elasticity of substitution

Tags: economics

I have a utility function with constant elasticity of substitution (CES) that takes the form:

$$u(c)=\frac{c^{1-\sigma}-1}{1-\sigma}$$ where $\sigma >0$ is a parameter.

Why is it that when $\sigma=1$, the function becomes $u(c)=\ln(c)$? I would have thought at this value of $\sigma$ the function is undefined as subbing in the value of $\sigma=1$ results in $(1-1)/(1-1)=0/0$ which is undefined.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why you´ve unaccepted my answer? Any specific reason?

Comment: Apologies that was a mistake! Have reaccepted.

Comment: No problem, newbie ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The utility function is not undefined for $\sigma=1$. You are right that in this form we cannot see what $u(c)$ is if $\sigma=1$. So we can apply the L´hôspital´s rule.

Let $f(\sigma)=c^{1-\sigma}-1$ and $g(\sigma)=1-\sigma$. Then we calculate the derivatives.

1. $f'(\sigma)= -c^{1 - \sigma}\cdot  \log(c)$
2. $g'(\sigma)=-1$

$$\lim_{\sigma\to 1} \frac{f'(\sigma)}{g'(\sigma)}=\lim_{\sigma\to 1} \frac{-c^{1 - \sigma}\cdot  \log(c)}{-1}=\lim_{\sigma\to 1} c^{1 - \sigma} \log(c)=\log(c)$$